# how can we get total number of items in cloudsearch?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudsearch

I am working on customer document (data like fname, lname, orderAmount etc.) which is configured on AWS CloudSearch. Now the situation is that I am showing this data on jquery datatable. for pagination I required to have total items available for search. Is there any way I can get count of all available document on cloudsearch ?

I am getting response for matching count, But not the total items available on cloudsearch doamin.

I have search for this under https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/what-is-cloudsearch.html but did not found any useful thing.

Any trick to get total document count on particular cloudsearch domain ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amazon does not have an easy way to fetch all the records, so we basically pass a condition which would never be true & return all the record.

**Key Points**

- Get only single item (pageSize = 1)
- Get item without fields

**For Example**

[http://search-movies-rr2f34ofg56xneuemujamut52i.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=(and+(id:0))&q.parser=structured&return=_no_fields&size=1](http://search-movies-rr2f34ofg56xneuemujamut52i.us-east-1.cloudsearch.amazonaws.com/2013-01-01/search?q=(and%20(id:0))&q.parser=structured&return=_no_fields&size=1)